# Groovy property access when multiple matching methods

Tags: groovy

In this specific instance, I was using CQ Groovy console v.6.1.2 to access property of a `com.day.cq.tagging.Tag` object.

`Tag` class has both `getNamespace()` and `isNamespace()` methods. When accessing `namespace` property by calling `tag.namespace`, I was given the result of `isNamespace()`, not `getNamespace()` - Is there a determined priority and/or any way to change this behavior or determine (and if so, then how/based on what) which one of the two will be called?

EDIT: code snippet to visualise the question a bit.

```
com.day.cq.tagging.Tag tag
// assign tag variable
def is = tag.isNamespace()
def get = tag.getNamespace()
def prop = tag.namespace
assert prop == is
assert prop != get
```

Why both asserts pass? Can I do anything to make none of them pass? How can I know whether `prop==is` or `prop==get` (by looking at documentation/code)?

EDIT2: `Tag` class is part of the Adobe CQ 5.6.1 tagging API and thus the only think I can provide about it is the [official documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/tagging/Tag.html)

Comment: Do you have some code to show?

Comment: @Danilo: I've added a code snippet to "visualise" the question.

Comment: @SandeepPoonia - I cannot - it's Adobe's closed source, but if you want to take a look at the documentation, then [go ahead](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/tagging/Tag.html)

Comment: Not sure about the CQ Groovy console, but by default groovy gives preference to getter method of a property.